# Accessing element within a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to access the root element a component with `this.$children.$el`, however, I'm getting undefined in the console. I can see the `$el` property on the object when I `console.log(this.$children)`, so I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Project
            v-for="project in projects"
            :key="project.sys.id"
            :title="project.fields.title"
            :images="project.fields.images"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Project from '~/components/Project'

export default {
    mounted() {    
        const projects = this.$children.$el
    },
    components: {
        Project
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: may you try `this.$root.$children`?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-children) `this.$children` returns an array of children components. You could see your child component by printing `this.$children[0]` and its root element by priting `this.$children[0].$el`.

If you have many children components and want to target a specific one, you can tag your component with a [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) attribute like below :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Project
            v-for="project in projects"
            :key="project.sys.id"
            :title="project.fields.title"
            :images="project.fields.images"
            ref="project"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Project from '~/components/Project'

export default {
    mounted() {    
        console.log(this.$refs.project)
    },
    components: {
        Project
    }
}
</script>
```